# ASP.NET FileUpload caches files?

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

I have a form with FileUpload control. Say, user chooses a file from his local disk, uploads it and then my site tells him that the file is in wrong format. The FileUpload control still retains the path to file.

Then the user makes neccessary corrections to his file and presses the upload button, assuming it will grab the updated version of his file. **But the server still receives the old version of file, which is without user corrections!** I even noticed that you can even rename or delete the local file after choosing it with FileUpload and it will still upload.

So my questions are:

- Does FileUpload control cache files in some fashion?
- Is this ASP.NET functionality or it's present in basic HTML  control?
- Can I remove this caching so that server always gets the latest version of the file?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `fileuploadId.Dispose()` on pageload to clear the control.

Comment: Yeah, I tried this. It resets FileUpload. That's like treating headache by cutting the head off. :D